# Is it possible to kill Iskatu in Adventure Mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

I did most of the hardcore achievements in Adventure Mode and never bothered with story. However, I cannot find Iskatu boss there. I've noticed that in Act III there is cursed chest which spawns Ghom. Is there some similar event to summon Iskatu? Is there any other way to fight him without doing story mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Iskatu is story mode only. Some bosses and events were taken out of Adventure Mode when it was first introduced and the Iskatu encounter has never been put back in.

[You'll just need to start up the story mode and go to Act IV.](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Iskatu)

[Bonus note: Stay away from the D3 forums about this subject, but here's a link anyway if you're into that sort of thing](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/12506722169)

Comment: That's sad. Well, I'm missing lots of conversation achievements, will try to do all of them in one last story run.

Comment: Oh man, good luck. There are guides out there but it can take longer to get the guides straight than to actually complete the story. You have to keep going back into town, back into town, back into town -> find the book find the book find the book. It's a pain, but very satisfying for achievement hunters